# I want to load JSON data, but I get HTML in response

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

## Error

I'm using someone else's `React` component which loads local data into the app. When I try to load the data in my UI, Chrome says:

> localhost:3000 says:
>
> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

The error is shown as a popup in the browser window. No error in the console.
[image]

## My Attempt

I checked the `Network` tab, the response is my `index.html` page, and the `Request URL` is

> http://localhost:3000/node_modules/vega-datasets/data/barley.json

[image]

I guess there is **something wrong with my path**. I'm using [Microsoft TypeScript React Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter), which uses the [Facebook create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and `npm start` to serve my webapp. **I'm not sure which directory** `http://localhost:3000/` is referring to just by looking at the [start.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d4dc63d3ca0e5af6a86b865aa71b95d4) and [paths.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3435c9069c8f77a884106e45e443b508) script. Here are the files that I think might be relevant:

config/[paths.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3435c9069c8f77a884106e45e443b508)

config/[webpack.config.dev.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0c7dd344ca7893efcf7c9eb6c44f0b02)

config/[webpackDevServer.config.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86e0c06b121a73be92b37ac9d8cc6225)

scripts/[start.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d4dc63d3ca0e5af6a86b865aa71b95d4)

[package.json](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dcdac2c497387cc274a768e8365f0066)

## Solution

`devserver/contentBase` is configured to my `public` folder. See Panther's comment below.

Comment: I dont see the `content-type` header in the request. It should be `application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: I dn think your devserver will pick files from `node_modules` folder. the `contentbase` is configured to be your `public` folder. So your `json` file should be under `public` folder.

Comment: Thank you @Panther I copied my data to the `public` folder and it's loading `json` now!